# Setting the Session Secure Only Flag Programmatically

Tags: java

In web.xml, you can make sure that the session cookie (JSESSIONID) is set as an SSL only cookie by the following:

```
<session-config>
  <cookie-config>
    <secure>true</secure>
  </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

Is there a way to achieve the same thing programmatically when you create the session?

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer. Here it is for the benefit of others:

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    ServletContext servletContext = servletContextEvent.getServletContext();
    SessionCookieConfig scc = servletContext.getSessionCookieConfig();
    scc.setSecure(true);
}
```

The code should obviously be added to your app's context listener.

Comment: any thoughts on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78065718/handling-secure-attribute-but-was-not-received-via-a-secure-connection-error-f